# xaml design doesnot work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml, xaml-designer

i can't see any control in xaml designer , i can click on them and go to behind code but can't see then , i reinstall VS 2012 but no luck , even if i create new project it will do the same , and this happen with blend too . i searched so so so so much to solve this problem , but no luck , please help me
PS : i installed vs 2010 sp1 , vs 2012 update 1
here the basic code of blank windows store app with a button

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I don't see any `Button` there. Your XAML as is will be blank.

Comment: VS recently shipped vs 2012 update 2 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912. It contains several fixes for XAML Designer as well, maybe it will fix your problem as well.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add a Button ..

Comment: Upload the project on SkyDrive/Dropbox so I can tell where's the problem your code or VS.

Comment: i said even if create new project .. the problem still happen .. beside: every thing was working fine , but it just crashed or buged for some reasone

Comment: outcoldman : the update didnot fix it

Answer (score 2):

AT LAST after 5 days searching . i found the problem , it was from my video card :
i have hp probook 4540s laptop , it has intel and amd video cards ,so i customize the setting to give me full graphics power , so i open Catalyst Control Center and  made the Power give me Maximize Performance (and here the problem started) i changed it to Optimize Performance and all came back to normal (OMG)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a ProBook 4740s and had the exact same problem which has been fixed by your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but you normally have to give the grid some kind of row or column definition.  Here is a grid that defines two rows:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="hello world"></Button>
</Grid>
```

The above works for me, but the following does NOT work:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="hello world"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: still not showing any design .. all i can see is layout of every control, that's all